# Succeeded in deploying verticle but I get this error : Result is already complete: succeeded

Tags: java, vert.x

i succeeded in deploying vertical but i still got this error : **Result is already complete: succeeded**. I don't understand why, I need some explanation this is  my Deploy class :

```
public class Deploy {
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Deploy.class);

private static void deployAsynchronousVerticalByIndex(Vertx vertx, int indexCurrentDeploy, JsonArray verticalArray, Future<Void> startFuture, JsonObject jsonObjectConfig) {
    JsonObject currentVertical = verticalArray.getJsonObject(indexCurrentDeploy);
    currentVertical.forEach(entry -> {
        logger.debug("Starting deploy of class: " + entry.getKey() + ", With the config: " + entry.getValue() + ".");

        DeploymentOptions optionsDeploy = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(jsonObjectConfig);
        ObservableFuture<String> observable = RxHelper.observableFuture();
        vertx.deployVerticle(entry.getKey(), optionsDeploy, observable.toHandler());

        observable.subscribe(id -> {
            logger.info("Class " + entry.getKey() + " deployed.");
            if (indexCurrentDeploy + 1 < verticalArray.size()) {
                deployAsynchronousVerticalByIndex(vertx, indexCurrentDeploy + 1, verticalArray, startFuture, jsonObjectConfig);
            } else {
                logger.info("ALL classes are deployed.");
                startFuture.complete();
            }
        }, err -> {
            logger.error(err, err);
            startFuture.fail(err.getMessage());
        });
    });
}

public static void deployAsynchronousVertical(Vertx vertx, JsonArray verticalArray, Future<Void> startFuture, JsonObject jsonObjectConfig) {
    deployAsynchronousVerticalByIndex(vertx, 0, verticalArray, startFuture, jsonObjectConfig);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you reuse your future between verticles, and have a race condition there.

Simplest way to fix that would be :

```
if (startFuture.isComplete()) {
   startFuture.complete();    
}
```

But that actually would only obscure the problem.

Extract your observable out of the loop, so it actually would listen only once for every vertice.

```
    JsonObject currentVertical = verticalArray.getJsonObject(indexCurrentDeploy);
    ObservableFuture<String> observable = RxHelper.observableFuture();
    currentVertical.forEach(entry -> {
    logger.debug("Starting deploy of class: " + entry.getKey() + ", With the config: " + entry.getValue() + ".");

        DeploymentOptions optionsDeploy = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(jsonObjectConfig);

        vertx.deployVerticle(entry.getKey(), optionsDeploy, observable.toHandler());
    });

    observable.subscribe(id -> {
        logger.info("Class " + id + " deployed.");
        if (indexCurrentDeploy + 1 < verticalArray.size()) {
            deployAsynchronousVerticalByIndex(vertx, indexCurrentDeploy + 1, verticalArray, startFuture, jsonObjectConfig);
        } else {
            logger.info("ALL classes are deployed.");

            if (startFuture.isComplete()) {
                startFuture.complete();
            }
        }
    }, err -> {
        logger.error(err, err);
        startFuture.fail(err.getMessage());
    });
```

Comment: thanks  a lot @alexey for  your  help  i'm  new  to  vert.x, this was  a  perfect  answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

and in addition to Extracting your observable out of the loop,
it is a good idea to use io.vertx.core.Promise instead of io.vertx.core.Future.
and use **promise.try**XXXX()

according to io.vertx.core.Promise.java documentation:

> Future is @deprecated. instead use Promise.

> tryFail is Like  fail but returns false when the promise is already
> completed instead of throwing IllegalStateException. and it returns
> true otherwise.

so...
instead of

```
if (startFuture.isComplete()) 
    startFuture.complete();
if (startFuture.isFail()) 
    startFuture.fail(err.getMessage());
```

use

```
promise.tryComplete()
promise.tryFail(err.getMessage());
```